# SQL Server : declare variables in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, sql-view

I've created a view and want to having a rolling data range. I know that local variables are not allowed in a view so wondering what the best way is. I don't want to my `DATEADD` in my `WHERE` as I am dealing with lots of data and so will slow it down significantly.

```
CREATE VIEW uvw_new_view 

DECLARE @startdate
DECLARE @enddate

SET @startdate =  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)  -- back 1 year
SET @enddate = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, , GETDATE()) + 4, -1) -- forward 3 years

//stuff 
WHERE startdate >= @startdate AND enddate <= @enddate
```

Cheers all in advance :)

Comment: Tag your question with the dtabase you are using.

Comment: i'M TERRIBLY SORRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are using SQL Server, based on the syntax.

You want a table-valued function.  For instance, a function that returns all dates within a range:

```
create function dates (
    @startdate date,
    @enddate date
) 
returns table
as
return
    with cte as (
          select @startdate as dte
          union all
          select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
          from cte
          where dte < @enddate
         )
     select dte
     from cte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0a88c0f4e8b95988568fcead7dcc57d2) is a db<>fiddle with this example.